# Select different runner tags for each parallel matrix job

Tags: gitlab-ci

[The documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#select-different-runner-tags-for-each-parallel-matrix-job) document is pretty clear on how to select a shared runner based on a *single* tag value. The document is however a lot less clear when the shared runner needs two or more tags.

Here is what I have working in my setup (company GitLab instance):

```yaml
variables:
  GIT_STRATEGY: none

.build-matrix:
  parallel:
    matrix:
    - IMAGE: "mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2022"
      TAG1: "windows2022"
      TAG2: "docker"
      TAG3: "docker" # cannot be empty string, hack: duplicate previous one
    - IMAGE: "mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0"
      TAG1: "linux"
      TAG2: "dind"
      TAG3: "docker"

build:
  extends: .build-matrix
  stage: build
  tags:
    - $TAG1
    - $TAG2
    - $TAG3
  image: $IMAGE
  script:
    - echo "hello world"
    - pwd
```

As you can see above I cannot use an array as variable in my `parallel` section. So I need to expand manually the array and use a trick to pass each individual tags down to the build stage.

Did I miss something from the documentation, or is there another way to select a runner based on **two or more** tags?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem or question here. If what you have is working, what needs to be improved upon in this model? What's the challenge with specifying multiple tags? You could also consider adding tags that are specific enough (`docker-dind-linux` as a single tag for example) on each runner so you only have to use one tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have works and, if using multiple tags, you'll need to use the same number of tags for each permutation, as you've described. You might also use `rules:variables:` with a condition like `if: $IMAGE == "..."` to the same effect, but that doesn't change much.

If you want to keep your configuration minimally verbose, you should create unique tags on your runner, so they can be referenced using just one tag, for example `docker-dind-linux` or `docker-windows`.

```yaml
.build-matrix:
  parallel:
    matrix:
    - IMAGE: "mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2022"
      TAG: "docker-windows"
    - IMAGE: "mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0"
      TAG: "docker-dind-linux"
  tags:
    - $TAG
```